# DNS-Block All Websites Except for Whitelisted Sites

Tags: linux, networking, dns, proxy

`echo 0.0.0.0 facebook.com >> /etc/hosts`
is a pretty simple solution to prevent facebook.com and its subsites from resolving to an IP address.
(This is also how Linux Mint's *Mint Nanny* works).

I would like to extend this to all sites except for a select few, however, I can't seem to find any workable solution on the web.

I have found some clues suggesting using a transparent proxy server, however I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

Can anyone post a concrete, straightforward recipe on how to achieve this simple goal (in an Unix-like operating system, preferably a GNU/Linux)?

Comment: How about only adding the white listed hosts to /etc/hosts and disabling external DNS lookup ?  (Note that people still can access those sites if they just use the sites IP rather than its name).

Answer (score 11):

Use dnsmasq.  This is a really neat service.

On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

edit /etc/dnsmasq.conf

add this line to make all sites redirect to localhost:

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
```

add these lines to make specific sites use the DNS server at 8.8.8.8:

```
server=/allowed.com/8.8.8.8
```

then restart the dnsmasq service:

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```

Comment: When I was using Ubuntu 18 this was working for me. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20 this doesn't work for me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to DNS block. Setting up an Apache mod_proxy and ProxyBlock would be enough.

Comment: Some details would be nice though